# You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". Typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, e2e-testing

I'm trying to run a command at npm start, but I get the message: "You seem to be not dependent on" @angular/core ". This is an error.
What could be the reason?
As it writes in the console: npm @angular/core -v it gets 5.4.2

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.3",
"applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.12",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"date-fns": "^1.28.5",
"deepmerge": "^1.5.1",
"fingerprintjs2": "^1.5.1",
"ng2-page-scroll": "^4.0.0-beta.9",
"ngx-mydatepicker": "2.1.2",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.4.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.4.3",
"@types/applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.4",
"@types/deepmerge": "^1.3.2",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-deploy-git": "^0.5.3",
"gulp-replace": "^0.6.1",
"husky": "^0.14.3",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"lint-staged": "^4.0.3",
"prettier": "^1.5.3",
"protractor": "^5.1.2",
"run-sequence": "^2.1.0",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "^2.5.2"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue to resolve this all you need to do is to

```
cd <project_name>
```

and then run the following command:

```
npm update
```

and than the project will be succesfully compiled.

Comment: This command will update all the packages listed to the latest version as well as it will also install the missing packages.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced the same issue while executing below command.

```
D:\My_Project>ng serve
```

Then I have followed below steps and it worked for me.

```
D:\My_Project>npm link
D:\My_Project>ng serve
```

Keep trying, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `node_modules` folder, `package-lock.json` file and then run:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npm i
```

Comment: npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

Comment: npm WARN deprecated @types/date-fns@2.6.0: This is a stub types definition for date-fns (https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns). date-fns provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/date-fns installed!
npm WARN ngx-dropdown@0.0.22 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-OWxKW/sihH+eRYJFuplfnBMMDPM= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-OWxKW/sihH+eRYJFuplfnBMMDPM= but got sha1-bvi87/W75iTIMcYNmjbLWU5LxCw=. (360058 bytes)

Comment: hmm, I edited and added two more lines which you could try.

Comment: and eventually - if you work on Windows and have some antivirus try to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred in my case when my node_modules folder is empty otherwise it will have bunch of folders inside. I used the "ng link" command to work it out.

My project name is Pipes, and my command prompt looks like this:

Pipes$ npm link

And finally you can execute ng serve to check it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **^** this, because something its get that version where the others files are effecting due to this version,

so always use the specific version in angular.

or you can use the following package.json here:

```
{
  "name": "artist-booking-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^4.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng2-scroll-to-el": "^1.0.0",

    "primeng": "^4.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
npm install @angular/core;
```

Then delete this file: `node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__`

And try to reload your ng server.